# How to make iterator to operate in single element in list comprehension when duplicate elements are present?

Tags: python, string, pandas, list-comprehension

I'm trying to convert strings like '24S', '36N' (representing latitude values) to 'S24' so that I can replace 'S' with '-' and 'N' with '+'. My dataframe contains two columns with such values.

My code looks something like this:

```py
def chng_to_str(df, col):
    for each in df[col]:
        lst= [char for char in each]
        lst= lst[-1:] + lst[:-1]
        new= ''
        new= new.join(lst)
        lst.clear()
        df.loc[df[col]== each, col]= new

dict1= {'Lat': ['23S', '32N', '45S', '23S'],
       'Lon': ['56E','65W', '49W', '32E']}
df= pd.DataFrame(dict1)
df.head()


    Lat Lon
0   23S 56E
1   32N 65W
2   45S 49W
3   23S 32E
```

I expected

```py
    Lat Lon
0   S23 E56
1   N32 W65
2   S45 W49
3   S23 E32
```

but the output i got is

```py
    Lat Lon
0   3S2 E56
1   N32 W65
2   S45 W49
3   3S2 E32
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.replace`:

```
df.replace('(\d+)(\w+)', '\\2\\1', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
   Lat  Lon
0  S23  E56
1  N32  W65
2  S45  W49
3  S23  E32
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.applymap(lambda x: x[-1] + x[:-1])
```

---

```
   Lat  Lon
0  S23  E56
1  N32  W65
2  S45  W49
3  S23  E32
```

Comment: `x[:len(x)-1]` can be shortened to `x[:-1]` :)

Comment: yup...just use apply with relevant column name.. @Niteshsawadia